# What field is a modding field mapped to after obfuscation?

Tags: minecraft-forge

For reflection purposes I need to know what the field name is after obfuscation, so I can do something like.

```
return ((Integer)ReflectionHelper
     .getPrivateValue((Class)EntityLivingBase.class, 
                      (Object)ent, 
                      new String[] { "recentlyHit", "field_70718_bc" }))
     .intValue();
```

How can I figure out this fieldname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are under linux/mac, or on windows use the [git bash shell](https://git-for-windows.github.io/)

Open up a bash terminal
cd into your modding directory

Then issue the following command:

```
grep -rnw './' -e "age" | awk -F: '/RENAME MAP/ {print $4}'
```

And you'll get output like this:

[image]